For devices running 34+ do I need to request both READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED and READ_MEDIA_IMAGES?
If I'm targeting SDK 34 and I'm on a device running 34, do I need to request both READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED and READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, or can I get away with just READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED?
